# How to display products by categories in different different pages in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to display products by categories in different different pages. eg.

- Shoes

  - Relaxo
  - Adidas
  - XYZ

Here, I want to show  all shoes of relaxo in one page and all shoes of adidas in another page and all shoes of xyz in third page. But as I am trying 
in relaxo cms page i write...

```
{{block type="core/template"name="parts.search" as="partsSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}
```

In its design layout update XML i write...

```
<reference name="content">

<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list_new.phtml">

<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>

<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">

<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

</block>

<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>

</block>

</reference>
```

It shows relaxo shoes in frontend.

But When I try same method for adidas and XYZ shoes it doesn't display there list view.

How to Solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: why you are creating new page for different categories ?  find custom product list module https://github.com/ergopalpatel/Custom-Product-List . You can set custom url key and set category id in registry and retrieve it in collection and filter it

Answer (score 2):

You can use magento object to filter.

Example:

```
$categoryId = 123; // a category id that you can get from admin
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->load();

print_r($products);
```